# Cordova - Feature tag in config.xml

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

I have created a cordova project using the CLI version 5.3.1 and added the iOS platform. I have also created a custom plugin and I understand that in order for the plugin to be configured to work, I need to add the following feature tag to my top level config.xml.

```
<feature name="MyPluginName">
    <param name="ios-package" value="MyPluginName" />
</feature>
```

After doing so and running

```
cordova build
```

in the CLI, I am expecting the iOS platform-specific config.xml to hold the above feature tag, but this does not seem to be the case. The feature tag still exists in the top level config.xml, but does not seem to be propagated to the platform specific config.xml.

In order for the plugin to work, after I run

```
corodva build
```

I must manually copy and past the feature tag into the platform-specific config.xml AND THEN the plugin seems to work. However this is not ideal as I would like to be able to just write the feature tag once, instead of after every build.

How do I configure my plugin properly?

Thanks.

Comment: You should put that on the plugin.xml of your plugin

Comment: Where should the plugin.xml file reside? Keep in mind that this isn't a plugin I installed via cordova plugin add pluginName.

Comment: Even if it's a custom plugin you created, it has to have the plugin.xml and you have to install it using the CLI, read the plugin development guide

Comment: I am facing the same problem with a custom plugin I created. Did you manage to solve the problem?